# Select a letter in a string

Tags: string, character, ada

I need to create an hash function in Ada that takes a string and returns an integer. 
what I did so far is :

```
function hash(Word: unbounded string) return Integer is
    h := 5381
    c := (first charater of "Word")
begin
    while c /= (end of "Word") loop
         h := h*33 + c;
         c := (next character of "Word");
    end while;
return h mod 20;
end hash;
```

I don't know how to select a character in Ada, how to say " I want the third character of the word "word", which is r.

Thanks for your help,

T.

Answer (score 3):

Review the services provided by the [Ada.Strings.Unbounded](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-4-5.html) package.

Answer (score 1):

As Marc has said, you will need to use [Ada.Strings.Unbounded](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-4-5.html) to get at the contents of `Word`.

There are two other problems you need to address:

- In Ada, there's no terminating character in an `Unbounded_String` (or in a `String`, come to that). Instead, write the loop as `for J in 1 .. (length of Word) loop`.
- Once you've extracted the `J`'th character, it's still a `Character` and you can't add it to `h` (I assume `h` is integral). `Character'Pos (Ch)` returns the numeric equivalent of the character, and that you *can* add.

Answer (score 1):

```ada
function hash(Word: Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String) return Integer is
-- First, because there's no manipulation of the string's
-- contents, doing the work on an unbounded-string is
-- rather pointless... so let's do our work on a regular --' fix for formatting
-- [static-length] string.
Working : String := Ada.Strings.Unbounded.To_String(Word);
-- Second, you need types in your declarations.
h : Integer := 5381;
c : Character := 'e'; --(first charater of "Word");
begin
-- Why use a 'while' loop here? Also, what if the 'word' is
-- abracadabra, in that case c [the first letter] is the 
-- same as the last letter... I suspect you want an index.

  for Index in Working'Range loop -- Was: while c /= EOW loop --'
    declare
    -- This is where that 'c' should actually be.
    This  : Character renames Working(Index);
    -- Also, in Ada characters are NOT an integer.
    Value : constant Integer := Character'Pos( This ); --'
    begin
    h := h*33 + value; -- PS: why 33? That should be commented.
    -- We don't need the following line at all anymore. --'
    --c := (next character of "Word");
    end;        
  end loop;
return h mod 20;
end hash;
```

Of course this could also be rewritten to take advantage of the new loop-constructs in Ada 2012.

```ada
function hash_2012(Word: Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String) return Integer is
    -- Default should be explained.
    Default : Constant Integer := 5381;
    Use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
begin
    -- Using Ada 2005's extended return, because it's a bit cleaner.
    Return Result : Integer:= Default do
        For Ch of To_String(Word) loop
            Result:= Result * 33 + Character'Pos(Ch); --'
        end loop;

        Result:= Result mod 20;
    End return;
end hash_2012;
```

...and I've got to ask, what happened to the formatter? This is just horrid.

Comment: Oh, yeah... you probably want to address the issue of overflow. For any string more than a few characters it's going to overflow integer since you're multiplying by 33 each time. 2^31 / (33+65) = 21913098... and that's not taking into account that every character is adding its value into this.